# Questions regarding python requests package

Tags: python, html, python-requests

So, I started learning about python's requests package lately and I got into a challenge.
At first I was given a link “http://pms.zelros.com/” that only gave me a tip : query param id must be an uuid v4

I started working on that and so far I've came up with this:

```
'''
def get_optimal_frequency(nb_of_requests=50):
    """
    This sends a number of request in a row to raise Error 429 and get the "optimal frequency" by setting it 
    to the maximal 'X-Rate-Limit-Remaining' that we got + 10% as a margin of error

    :param nb_of_requests: The number of requests sent to raise the Error
    :return: The safe time to wait between requets in ms
    :rtype: int
    """
    session =  requests.Session()
    query = uuid.uuid4()
    optimal_frequency = 0
    headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Chrome/79.0.3945.88',
    }
    for i  in range(nb_of_requests):
        response = session.get("http://pms.zelros.com", params={'id':query}, headers=headers)
        if response.headers.get('X-Rate-Limit-Remaining') is not None and int(response.headers.get('X-Rate-Limit-Remaining')) > optimal_frequency:   
            optimal_frequency = int(response.headers.get('X-Rate-Limit-Remaining'))
    return 1.1*optimal_frequency


def spam_until_score(score):
    """
    This sends requests with a uuidv4 until the desired score is reached

    :param score: The score wanted
    :return: The response of the last request
    :rtype: requests.models.Response
    """

    start = time.time()
    current_score = 0
    query = uuid.uuid4()
    session =  requests.Session()
    optimal_frequency = get_optimal_frequency()
    headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Chrome/79.0.3945.88',
    }
    while(current_score < score):
        response = session.get("http://pms.zelros.com", params={'id':query}, headers=headers)
        dict_response = response.json()
        if (int(dict_response.get('score')) < current_score):
            break
        else:
            current_score = int(dict_response.get('score'))
        time.sleep(optimal_frequency/1000)
    end = time.time()
    duration = end - start
    return response, duration
```

But I'm stuck, the goal is to reach 1 000 000 score and getting to 10 000 took 5536s.

The help I've got so far are these:

**Level 10000**

From /people

Let's add a people payload

"people": [x, x, x]

**Level 2000**

And you can add a score payload to optimize your preparation

**Level 700**

You can /prepare your request.

**Level 300**

Nice start. It was easy :)

Let's use some fancy http verbs.

**Level 100**

You already know that you cannot spam me.

But do you know that there is an optimal frequency to contact me ?

**Level 0**

Hello !

Welcome to the Zelros challenge

The goal is to reach a one millon score.

Sorry for the long message but here are my questions :

-Is there a way to send more requests without raising error 429, maybe using parallel requests ? If yes, how should I do it ?
-I don't really get how preparing requests could help me.
-What other html methods besides the GET one could I be using ?

Thanks for your time and help